# Passing arbitrary data to a child directive

Tags: angular, typescript, wijmo

I am using Wijmo's `wjFlexGridDetail` directive, and want to control which rows display a detail grid based on whether a "detailData" array in the component contains any matching data.  The `rowHasDetail` property takes a function that uses the outer grid's row as input and returns a boolean.  I want to do something like this:

```
<ng-template wjFlexGridDetail let-item="item" [rowHasDetail]="hasDetail">

hasDetail (row): boolean {
    return this.detailData.filter(item => item.ID === row.dataItem.ID).length > 0
} // detailData is undefined when I try this
```

but this doesn't work because `this` in the scope of the function refers to the `wjFlexGridDetail` object, which doesn't contain the data I'm trying to check against.  I tried binding it as a data attribute:

```
<ng-template wjFlexGridDetail let-item="item" [rowHasDetail]="hasDetail" [attr.data-detail]="detailData">
```

but got an error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Property binding data-detail not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

Is there another way to get that data into the scope of the function?  Or specifically for the `wjFlexGridDetail` usage, is there another way to accomplish my goal (I want it to only display the + expansion button for rows that have detail data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it feels like bad Angular so hopefully there's still a better answer out there.

The `bind` function can add any data to the scope of the function.  Instead of passing in the function directly, call a function that returns the function and bind the data to it.

```
<ng-template wjFlexGridDetail let-item="item" [rowHasDetail]="hasDetail()"><!-- note the () -->

hasDetail (): (row) => boolean {
    return function (row): boolean {
        return this && this.filter(item => item.ID === row.dataItem.ID).length > 0
    }.bind(this.detailData)
}
```

Changing the scope of the function to `detailData` allows the comparison to be made, but it really doesn't feel like the "correct" way of doing things.